# Why do get a "TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable" on a series with strings and NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, function, apply, iterable

For a series containing strings and NaN values, why does `series.apply(not_happy)`

where not_happy is defined by:

```py
def not_happy(element):
    if 'subtring' in element:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

gives the error `"TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable"`

Comment: What's the dtype of your series ?  String (object) type ?  If yes, see if your series contains any NaN values.  NaN values are considered of float type in Pandas.

Comment: If your function is just looking to return `True` or `False` based on the presence of a substring, you  might want to look into [Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains) which would handle floats without a TypeError

Comment: the series.value_counts() gives a "dtype: int64" but i can see both NaN (which I understand now its a type of float) and strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the values in the series you're applying the funciton on in not of str type or probably you have some missing values.